# Kubuntu 20.04 frozen after a while on HP Elitedesk 800 G1

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, freeze

I have installed Kubuntu on my HP Elitedesk 800 G1.
Everything is fine excepted one thing.
Kubuntu is sometimes freezing.
I write 'sometimes' because I don't undestand what causes the freeze.
After x minutes, the system is programmed to go in stand-by. Sometimes eveything is ok for 4 days. I press a key and the computer wakes up, login, perfect.
But it happens that nothing is responding. It happens in stand bu mode and during use.
When it happens, mouse doen't move, not possible to open a terminal using CTRL+T, not possible to swith to another session with CTRL+ALT+Fx.
If it happens when computer is in stand by, I see the LED (which is flashing slowly in standby) going to ON, I hear the fans starting, I see red light from the mouse, but screens still stay OFF.
In that cases the only thing I can do is ON/OFF button for few seconds to shutdown the computer and start it again.
The install has been done with the same install on my HP Elitebook laptop and that one is totally perfect.

Any idea ? Or anyone has the same problem ?

I mention that I am not a expert in Linux ;)

Comment: Again this morning. Computer in stand-by. I've pressed a key, waked up. Red light of the mouse is continuously blinking, fans have started, computer led continuously blinking. Computer is waked up. No reaction. Screens (1 displayport, 1 DVI and 1 VGA) are still in power off. Nothing else to do than switch the computer off and start it again :(

Answer (score 0):

On my EliteBook, in the HP BIOS, there are fan settings, f1(etc.) settings, what hardware is activated by default, and a bunch more.

On mine (and I hazard a guess that it is the same on yours), to enter BIOS:  shutdown completely, wait a few seconds, power on, hit escape (once or twice, if you hit it too much you will esc the BIOS, then when in BIOS, hit f10 to get into a more detailed bios.  In advanced settings, you can change hardware from 'view,' to change, (I just put them all on change), SAVE, then you can go back (hit esc) and then somwhere still under advanced you should now have the options to enable disable the onboard hardware.

ESPECIALLY, there are options for wake from sleep, deep sleep or not.  Possibly for you're case, a gentle push of power button will wake from sleep, then maybe spacebar to get monitor to display something.  :)